# Prevent html rendering from a non-browser GET request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connect-mongo

Im currently using Node & Express to build my application

My authentication function looks like this:

```
exports.isAuthenticatedLocal = function(req, res, callback) {
    // console.log(req.headers);
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
};
```

This is called in my users router:

```
router.get('/profile', authController.isAuthenticatedLocal, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', { user : req.user });
});
```

So that all works with the profile page being rendered from a browser. However if a user is logged in and posts a `GET` request to `localhost/profile` the whole page will be sent back with all the user details.

The problem is that I'm using `connect-mongo` for a persistent passport connection.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

...

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db.connection });

app.use(session({
        key: 'connect.sid',
        secret: 'secret',
        store: sessionStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Using a simple session will not trigger `req.isAuthenticated()` from a non-browser `GET` request and the login page, which I'm redirecting to, is rendered instead (which is fine).

```
app.use(session({
        key: 'connect.sid',
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

So how can I be able to keep a persistent connection with connect-mongo and prevent all pages that users are authenticated on, from being rendered? Is there a specific header I should look for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the user-agent header and see if it's a browser or not. You can use something like [express-useragent](https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent) to help you out.

The User-Agent header is not required, can be spoofed and thus should not be considered as an absolute truth.

I don't think your route should behave differently depending on what it thinks the client is or isn't. You should have a route for the page rendering, and a different route for the raw data.